# Use of choice variables with cookiecutter version 2.1.1 failing with clueless error

Tags: cookiecutter-django, cookiecutter

I am using the cookiecutter python library with the following version : `Cookiecutter 2.1.1`. I'm working with this version to use some of the v2 features so I don't wish to downgrade the version.
In the parameters that I'm using, I have something like this :

```
{
    "project_name": "project_name",
    "use_aws": [
        true,
        false
    ]
}
```

When running the following cookiecutter command, `cookiecutter . --no-input project_name="test" use_aws=True` locally or in my GitHub Actions pipeline, it fails with the following error:

`ValueError: True provided for choice variable use_aws, but the choices are [True, False].`

I tried multiple typos like True, "True", true, 1, etc. but nothing worked so far. I found a post mentionning that downgrading to v1.7.3 worked but that's not something I can do.
I'm not sure what exactly should be passed so the value is accepted...